# How can I get text from SelectionItem

Tags: kivy, kivy-language, kivymd

AttributeError: 'SelectionItem' object has no attribute 'text'

Hey , How can I get text from SelectionItem , where ; a OneLineAvatarListItem is SelectionItem?! Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using Python3.X and Regular Expressions which extracts only alphanumeric words including spaces and full stops(which would be necessary for forming a syntactically correct phrase(s))

import re

new_text = ''.join(re.findall('[A-Za-z0-9. ]', SelectionItem))

print(new_text)

Comment: Thank you, I solved the problem by using (SelectionItem.children[Index of OneLineAvatarListItem].text)

Comment: The comment from @anairaqi worked for me.